# Html change div content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, rest

I'm having a struggle. It's not one of these questions how to do it but more like how to do that better.

[What im trying to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zbgfC.png)

Also I want to load rest into content when clicking on nav's

My question is what's "proper" or correct approach to do it without making a mess in a code.

How I done it so far

```
<li><a class="navelement" data-url="resources/web/loadit.html" href="#">navbar A</a></li>
```

And used jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.navelement').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault;
    $('#content').load($(this).data('url'));
});
$('.navelement:eq(0)').click();
```

});

I like this approach but I need to execute ajax rest call each time I change navbar.

Second approach I can think off is to hide/show in css div's. Any tip will be appreaciated.

Comment: If you want to "load something" into the div, then that content has to be "loaded" (using ajax). If you just want to change the content but already have it, you can use `$('#content').load(new_html_content)`. Or, as you say, have all the content loaded but hidden with css, and show/hide as necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I suggest to you is , first load all your html nav in the content and hide them (adding class) , also set foreach generated div a custom class (by example I added the index of nav element ) , with this you'll prevent multiple ajax loading ( only once ).

then , after clicking on  each nav just show it's content by refering to the generated class by example (nav1 ,nav2, nav 3)

Please find bellow a working snippet

```js
$(function() {
  $(".navelement").each(function(index, elm) {
    if ($(elm).data("url")) {
      var navElment = $("<div class='navdiv nav" + index + " hidden'>").load($(elm).data("url"));



      $("#content").append(navElment);

      $(elm).on("click", function() {
        $(".navdiv").addClass("hidden");
        $(".navdiv.nav" + index).removeClass("hidden");
      })
    }


  })




})
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}

ul li {
  display: inline;
  padding:5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><a class="navelement" data-url="https://httpbin.org/get?text=navAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA" href="#">navbar A</a></li>
  <li><a class="navelement" data-url="https://httpbin.org/get?text=navBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB" href="#">navbar B</a></li>
  <li><a class="navelement" data-url="https://httpbin.org/get?text=navCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC" href="#">navbar C</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="content">

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, that's what im trying to do right now :)

Answer (score 1):

Both of your approaches are correct but decision making points would be how frequently the data in div is changed and how much bandwidth will it cost to keep all divs loaded with data.

If data in div is frequently changed then I would suggest to use approach 2, i.e. load all divs once and hide and show the required one. This will improve the performance as ajax calls over network has time latency. Using approach 2 in this case will improve UI experience. This is also called as eager loading.

But in case if you have heavy data and user need not require all the data you have loaded then it will cause unnecessary loading of all divs which could consume considerable bandwidth and also cause long initial loading of page. In this case approach 1 is recommended. This is called as lazy loading.

Comment: Thank you , you pretty much answered what i'd asked for